# Из таблицы расстояний в libreOffice извлечь расстояние между двумя пунктами

Tags: excel-формулы, libre-office

Делаю таблицу путевого листа.

Есть лист, на котором высчитывается пройденный километраж между двумя точками. Значения записаны на отдельный лист.

Нужна формула, которая высчитывает по двум точкам, какой километраж пройден.

Например: в первой ячейке адрес откуда мы выехали, во-второй - куда приехали, а в третьей формула показывает сколько километров проехали, беря данные из таблицы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: >> *Значения записаны на отдельный лист*- Для чего покзываете эту таблицу, если нужные данные на отдельном листе? Если это и есть те данные - где эти три ячейки,о которых пишете?

Comment: три ячейки где угодно могут быть. Мне нужно следущее: в 1 ячейку я ввожу (например) Базарная 14, во 2 - Коммунаров 17, а в 3 ячейке будет формула, которая исходя из данной таблицы вычислит, что расстояние между этими двумя точками = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A2: "*Базарная 14*"

B2: "*Коммунаров 17*"

```
=ВПР(A2;Километраж!$A$1:$L$12;ПОИСКПОЗ(B2;Километраж!$A$1:$L$1;0);0)
```

Формула для `Excel`. Функции в английской версии - `VLOOKUP, MATCH`

Для `libre-office`, возможно, нужно заменить разделитель.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое